# Сравнение BigDecimal ">="

Tags: java

Есть ли более короткая запись сравнения `BigDecimal chisl1 >= chisl2`, чтобы не писать два условия в `if`?

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal chisl1 = new BigDecimal(5);
    BigDecimal chisl2 = new BigDecimal(5);

    if (chisl1.compareTo(chisl2) == 1 || chisl1.compareTo(chisl2) == 0) {
        System.out.println("chisl1 >= chisl2");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `chisl1.compareTo(chisl2) >= 0`

Comment: @extrn Ответы в ответы

Comment: Точно, спасибо большое

Comment: @defaultlocale было уже скорее всего, задача-то типичная, а если нет, может кто-нибудь решит подробнее расписать.

Comment: @extrn Не было, по крайней мере я не нашел. И никто не будет расписывать подробнее, т.к. ответ уже дан в коментах. Теперь вопрос будет долго висеть в неотвеченных, затем удален по таймеру. Видите что Вы натворили? :) Исправляйте теперь.

Comment: @extrn Что тут расписывать? что `(a > b || a = b)` эквивалентно `a >= b`? Может, тогда стоит расписать, что `a + b` равно `b + a`?

Comment: Вот и весь ответ chisl1.compareTo(chisl2) >= 0

Comment: @m.vokhm не недооценивайте мой графоманию :)

Comment: @defaultlocale благодарю за напутствие :)

Answer (score 4):

```java
chisl1.compareTo(chisl2) >= 0
```

Единственный важный момент: нужно избегать таких сравнений, как

```java
chisl1.compareTo(chisl2) == 1
```

> int compareTo(T o)
>
> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a **negative integer**, **zero**, or a **positive integer** as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

`compareTo` не обязан возвращать 1, если текущий экземпляр больше, он вполне может вернуть другое положительное число. Например, такая реализация вполне корректна:

```java
public class MyByte implements Comparable<MyByte> {
    private byte value;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyByte other) {
        return this.value - other.value;
    }

    ...
}
```